# RegEx using python extracting specific word followed with other three word more than once

Tags: python, regex, text-mining

I need to extract the word lack with one or 3 words following it from free text using RegEx,

```
import re
import string
Text = "lack of stair handrails, slippery surfaces, tripping hazards, lack of bathroom grab bars, lack floor"
new_data = re.search(r"(lack (\w+\W+){3})", Text)

print(new_data.group())
```

the result I got is only one sentence

```
lack of stair handrails,
```

but I need the result to be

```
lack of stair handrails
lack of bathroom grab bars
lack floor
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can match at least 1 word after `lack` and then exclude matching the comma from `\W` and repeat that 0-2 times so there can be 1-3 words after lack.

Note that if you want a max of 3 words after `lack`, the match given the text `lack of bathroom grab bars` will be `lack of bathroom grab`

If you want to match 1 or more words after it, you can change `{0,2}` to `*`

```
\black \w+(?:[^\w,]\w+){0,2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IghdyW/1)

If there should not be another `lack` matched, you can check the matched word after it:

```
\black (?!lack\b)\w+(?:[^\w,](?!lack\b)\w+){0,2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8pZXm1/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in Python 3.9+ you might like to try out an open source package I published recently called pregex. By using pregex, you can build your pattern as such:

```py
from pregex import *

pre = \
    "lack" + \
    op.Either(
        3 * (tk.Space() + Word()),
        tk.Space() + Word()
    )
```

You can then even fetch the underlying regex pattern:

```py
regex = pre.get_pattern()
```

which returns the RegEx pattern that you want:

```
lack(?:(?: \b\w+\b){3}| \b\w+\b)
```

Note though that the above pattern will result in the following matches:

```
['lack of stair handrails', 'lack of bathroom grab', 'lack floor']
```

Since you wanted 1 or 3 words after "lack", the match "lack of bathroom grab" does not include the word "bars", though this can be easily fixed:

```py
pre = \
    "lack" + \
    op.Either(
        qu.AtLeastAtMost(tk.Space() + Word(), n=3, m=4),
        tk.Space() + Word()
    )
```

which results in the following pattern:

```
lack(?:(?: \b\w+\b){3,4}| \b\w+\b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(\black\b[^,]*)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZsxN1W/1)

Explanation:

1. `\b` is to limit the match to the word `'lack'` and not that substring inside another word;
2. `[^,]*` matches all character except a `','`.

Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> s="lack of stair handrails, slippery surfaces, tripping hazards, lack of bathroom grab bars, lack floor"
>>> re.findall(r'\black\b[^,]*',s)
['lack of stair handrails', 'lack of bathroom grab bars', 'lack floor']
```